# Looking for documentation describing the automatic import of public key certificate from a smart card (Windows 7)

Tags: .net, cryptography, smartcard

A few of the current softwares solutions in .NET 4.0 i'm dealing with, are utilizing the automatic public key certificate import functionality from a smart card to a personal cert store (Assuming the vendor minidriver is installed and the appropriate services up).

For personal reasons, i need referative documentation (Any MSDN article would do) on the behavior. Why the import happens, how it happens, what platform OS-s are supported, keywords, what windows services must be up etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404288(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Jackpot, completely missed it even though i've browsed that reference a few times.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by CSPs provided by hardware vendors, not by applications themselves. Consequently, procedures and limitations are specific to each vendor.